# What language or framework commonly uses tags like "<!--ls:begin[stylesheet]-->"

Tags: templates, frameworks, content-management-system

You will see it in the source code of many web sites as follows:

```
<!--ls:begin[stylesheet]-->
<!--ls:end[stylesheet]-->
```

It appears to be some method of moving pieces defined in the body of some templating engine to the <head> of the the document (or wherever makes sense).

For example, see the HTML for this site: view-source:http://www.theaa.com/

Comment: I'm impressed, this question is 14 minutes old, and already indexed by google.

Answer (score 3):

Those tags are produced by LiveSite, which is part of TeamSite enterprise CMS now owned by HP.
Back in the days the company that found it was called Interwoven, then bought by Autonomy and now days it's HP.

http://www.autonomy.com/products/teamsite

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is [Live Site](https://livesite.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Yeah I searched for this same question too...

All I found was this but it doesn't mean they aren't using a white-labelled product http://www.limelight.com/web-content-management/